# Why can't I specialize a C++ class template on float?

Tags: c++, templates, template-specialization

I have the following class template:

```
template<typename T, T n> class Some
{
public:
    Some() : v(n) {}
    T get() const { return v ; }
private:
    T v;
};
```

I happily can specialize on an int, just like:

```
template <>
class Some<int, 0>
{
public:
    Some() : v(0) {}
    int get() const {return v;}
private:
    int v;
};
```

However if I try to make the same with `float`:

```
template <>
class Some<float, 0>
{
public:
    Some() : v(0) {}
    float get() const {return v;}
private:
    float v;
};
```

I get ugly compilation errors:

```
 error: 'float' is not a valid type for a template non-type parameter
     class Some<float, 0>
                    ^
```

Why? And how can I make the class work for `float`s also?

Comment: because floating point type cannot be treated as non-type template parameter, see e.g. [here](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/c%2b%2b/460/templates/16713/non-type-template-parameter#t=201608191145444374984) which types are allowed

Comment: "making the class work" requires more information on what the class' behaviour should be. You know you can't have a float non-type parameter, but is it OK for `n` to be, say, unsigned long long?

Comment: @W.F. yup, that is also what the compiler says... but what is the reasoning behind it?

Comment: @fritzone from "C++ Templates: The Complete Guide" by by Nicolai M. Josuttis; David Vandevoorde: `Not being able to use floating-point literals (and simple constant floating-point expressions) as template arguments has historical reasons. Because there are no serious technical challenges, this may be supported in future versions of C++ (see Section 13.4 on page 210).` Well - the future is not yet now.